# What levels do each armor tier drop?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I have had extremely varied luck with armor drops on my various characters. So I find myself wondering: **at what level is each armor tier supposed to start dropping?**

For instance, if you wear heavy armor, you will see these different tiers drop:

- Iron
- Chainmail
- Steel
- Azurite
- Sylvanite
- Prismere

I know Iron armor starts dropping at level 1. And I *think* Azurite starts dropping at level 13-ish. But what are the actual numbers?